# HTTP errors while making a request through a proxy

Tags: c++, http

I want to know how to make an HTTP request through a proxy using Socket.

I was looking through documentation on Internet, and many people said that to do it I must connect to the proxy server and send a packet with the following header:

```
send(Socket, "CONNECT http://icanhazip.com:80 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n", strlen("CONNECT http://icanhazip.com:80 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"), 0);
```

That website returns the current public IP, but, unfortunately, every proxy server I tried returned errors instead of the webpage's HTML source.

This is my actual code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try {

        int Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        sockaddr_in SockAddr;
        memset(&SockAddr, 0, sizeof(SockAddr));
        SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
        SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("198.169.246.30");

        int iResult = connect(Socket, (struct sockaddr *)& SockAddr, sizeof(SockAddr));
        if (iResult != 0) {
            std::cout << "I can't connect :(.";
            getchar();
            return 1;
        }
        std::cout << "Connected.\n";
send(Socket, "CONNECT http://icanhazip.com:80 HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n", strlen("CONNECT http://icanhazip.com:80 HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"), 0);

 char buffer[10000];
        int nDataLength;
        while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 10000, 0)) > 0) {
            int i = 0;
            while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
                std::cout << buffer[i];
                i += 1;
            }
        }
        iResult = close(Socket);
    }
    catch (...) {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

What can I do to fix it? Or, what other solution should I look into?

Comment: ... so what errors do they return?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning what the errors were.

Comment: @immibis I didn't specify that because sometimes I get `HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Timeout` and sometimes something like `404 not found`

Answer (score 0):

Old Chinese proverb say, "before writing code, better to read specification"

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230

by following links in the document:

> A client sending a CONNECT request MUST send the authority form of
> request-target (Section 5.3 of [RFC7230]); i.e., the request-target
> consists of only the host name and port number of the tunnel
> destination, separated by a colon.  For example,

> ```
> CONNECT server.example.com:80 HTTP/1.1
> ```

```
 Host: server.example.com:80
```

source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.6

Comment: I've just readed that document, but I still don't understand: what part of my question are you referring to?

Comment: @jmp1212 having followed the link in RFC 7230, answer updated. You could have done this...

Comment: I could have done what? Did you see I already send the following header `CONNECT http://icanhazip.com:80 HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n`?.

Comment: You could have followed the link to RFC7231 (linked above) and read that you MUST send the `Host: ` line (emphasis in the RFC, it's not mine).

Comment: so I need to  send `Host: http://icanhazip.com:80\r\n\r\n` instead of `CONNECT http://icanhazip.com:80 HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n`?

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. I think all you said is wrong as you are wrong-informed (I'm not criticizing nobody).

Comment: you need to send both!